# TypeORM does not make further query for nested object

Tags: postgresql, typeorm, typegraphql

I'm currently using PostgresQL with typeORM, as well as Typegraphql. With the `ManyToOne` (User has many orderItems) relationship, somehow I cannot query for the nested object relation. I set the `logging: true` and saw that there is no `SELECT` query for the `User` entity. However, I think the query should be automatically generated giving the relation I defined in the Entity according to TypeORM.

In CartItem.ts `Entity`

```
@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class CartItem extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  @Field()
  id!: number;

  @Column()
  @Field()
  userId: string;

  @Field(() => User, { nullable: true })
  @ManyToOne((type) => User, (user) => user.cartItems)
  user: User;
```

In User.ts `Entity`

```
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
  @Field()
  id!: string;

  @OneToMany((type) => CartItem, (cartItem) => cartItem.user)
  cartItems: CartItem[];
```

In cartItem.ts `Resolver`

```
  @Mutation(() => CartItem)
  @UseMiddleware(isAuth)
  async createCartItem(
    @Arg("input") input: CartItemInput,
    @Ctx() { req }: MyContext
  ): Promise<CartItem> {
    const newCart = await CartItem.create({
      quantity: input.quantity,
      userId: req.session.userId,
      mealkitId: input.mealkitId,
    }).save();

    return newCart;
```

With the following graphql `Query`, user would return null even though I'm supposed to get the username of the user

```
query cartItems{
  cartItems {
    id
    quantity
    userId
    user{
      username
    }
    
  }
}
```

Here is the response I received

````
{
  "data": {
    "cartItems": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "quantity": 2,
        "userId": "5619ffb2-6ce2-42cf-bd5c-042f2685a045",
        "user": null
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "quantity": 10,
        "userId": "5619ffb2-6ce2-42cf-bd5c-042f2685a045",
        "user": null
      }
    ]
  }
}```
````

Comment: You are not showing the cartItems query resolver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this myself and in my query resolver I had to `leftJoinAndSelect` all of the sub-objects to get it to work.  You aren't showing your query resolver, but something like

```
async cartItems(): Promise<CartItem[]> {
    return await getConnection()
        .createQueryBuilder(CartItem, 'cartItem')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('cartItem.user', 'user', 'cartItem.userId = user.id')
        .getMany()
}
```

Comment: But what if I don't want to fetch not only user's cartitems, but also
user's cartitems and their users and their cartitems and their users... etc - then do I have to write .leftJoinAndSelect many many times, or is there an another way?

Comment: Do not do that (use leftJoinAndAndSelect) many times if the result is going to be multiple records.  If you do it 2 or more times, you will get very bad performance.  It's ok if the result is a single record.

Comment: I have not found a way to do it with a single query. I do the main query and then fill in the the null fields with sub queries after.  This kind of makes sense as there really isn't a way in SQL to form one query that can get multiple sub-detail-queries and these just turn into a single SQL statement